# Estilos CSS dentro de textarea

Tags: php, html, color, textarea, echo

Necesito ayuda con un programa en *PHP*. Tengo un *textarea* y un código que hace que en el *textarea* se muestre "Hola".

¿Cómo puedo hacer que ese hola esté en rojo y que el "Adiós", que va después, en azul?

**Codigo PHP:**

```
<textarea name="consola" rows="8" cols="80">
<?php
            echo("Hola");
            echo("Adios");
?>
</textarea>
```

---

He intentado el codigo js, css y html pero me da error. Asi lo he puesto

```html
<div class="Consola">
          <script type="text/javascript">
            const colorMap = {"hola": "red", "adios": "blue"};
            let textArea = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
            let customArea = document.querySelector(".custom-area");
            let backdrop = document.querySelector(".backdrop");

            //Aqui simularemos todo el textarea dentro del custom area.

            textArea.addEventListener("input", function()
            {
              customArea.innerHTML = applyColors(textArea.value);
            });

            textArea.addEventListener("scroll", function()
            {
              backdrop.scrollTop = textArea.scrollTop;
            });

            //Aqui haremos el cambio de estilos.
            function applyColors(text)
            {
              //Aqui usamos regex y con la bandera gi para que no distinga entre mayusc y minusc
              let re = new RegExp(Object.keys(colorMap).join("|"), "gi");

              //le agregamos el estilo
              return text.replace(re, function(m)
              {
                let c = colorMap[m.toLowerCase()];
                return `<spam style="color:${c}">${m}</spam>`;
              });
            }
          </script>
          <style media="screen">
            .backdrop, #myTextArea {
              font: 12px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
              letter-spacing: 1px;
              width: 300px;
              height: 100px;
            }

            #myTextArea {
              margin: 0;
              position: absolute;
              border-radius: 0;
              background-color: transparent;
              color: transparent;
              caret-color: #555555;
              z-index: 2;
              resize: none;
            }

            .backdrop {
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 1;
              border: 2px solid transparent;
              overflow: auto;
              pointer-events: none;
            }

            .custom-area {
              white-space: pre-wrap;
              word-wrap: break-word;
            }
          </style>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="backdrop">
              <div class="custom-area">
                hola
              </div>
            </div>
            <textarea id="myTextArea" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: No puedes, dentro de un `textarea` solo se muestra valor, pero no se interpreta HTML ni CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desafortunadamente no se puede, pero encontré una solución, dentro de este [articulo](https://codersblock.com/blog/highlight-text-inside-a-textarea/) podemos simular el uso de `textarea` usando css y js, asi que aplicando lo indicado podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const colorMap = {"hola": "red", "adios": "blue"};
let textArea = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
let customArea = document.querySelector(".custom-area");
let backdrop = document.querySelector(".backdrop");

//Aqui simularemos todo el textarea dentro del custom area.

textArea.addEventListener("input", function()
{
    customArea.innerHTML = applyColors(textArea.value);
});

textArea.addEventListener("scroll", function()
{
    backdrop.scrollTop = textArea.scrollTop;
});

//Aqui haremos el cambio de estilos.
function applyColors(text)
{
    //Aqui usamos regex y con la bandera gi para que no distinga entre mayusc y minusc
    let re = new RegExp(Object.keys(colorMap).join("|"), "gi");

    //le agregamos el estilo
    return text.replace(re, function(m)
    {
        let c = colorMap[m.toLowerCase()];
        return `<spam style="color:${c}">${m}</spam>`;
    });
}
```

```css
.backdrop, #myTextArea {
  font: 12px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

#myTextArea {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  caret-color: #555555;
  z-index: 2;
  resize: none;
}

.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  overflow: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.custom-area {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="backdrop">
    <div class="custom-area">
        <!-- Aqui se posicionara el texto con el estilo -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
</div>
```